# Retrieving Coordinates from marker in mapbox

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, mapbox

I'm Working on laravel project and I made a Mapbox map with a draggable marker.
and I need to get the coordinates of the marker,
but I don't understand what is the best approach to doing that.

How can I retrieve the coordinates from the marker and store it in my database?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is using the approach used in the official example for movable markers:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-marker/

```
var coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates');
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [0, 0],
zoom: 2
});
 
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  draggable: true
})
.setLngLat([0, 0])
.addTo(map);
 
function onDragEnd() {
 var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
 coordinates.style.display = 'block';
 coordinates.innerHTML =
  'Longitude: ' + lngLat.lng + '<br />Latitude: ' + lngLat.lat;
}
 
marker.on('dragend', onDragEnd);
```